# Codeigniter - htaccess rewrite to hide wordpress folder

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

On root of my server, I have codeigniter with htaccess. I have created a wp/ folder along codeigniter's sub-folders (e.g. application, config) in which I have placed all the wordpress files. Now when someone types

```
www.abc.com
```

i redirect him to

```
www.abc.com/wp/
```

but I want to hide wp in the url. How can I achieve this without modifying my current file structure? I want wordpress to be my site's front and codeigniter to be my site's backend. The file structure is shown below:

[image]

Comment: why dont you modify your Codeigniter routes?

Comment: Can you copy and paste your file structure from your command prompt  `tree` -command here? This will give us a better visual of what you actually have in your directories.

Comment: Yes plz guide, in this scenario, how can I modify CI routes.

Answer (score 0):

In your root directory, create a .htaccess with following codes. This will map all your http requests to the /wp/ directory.

```
# ==>Initializaion…
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# ==>Without this line, your /wp/ directory may become visible sometimes
DirectorySlash Off

# ==>Map everything to your /wp/ directory
RewriteRule (.*) /wp/$1 [L]
```

You also want to hide the /wp/ directoy from URL. For this, create another .htaccess in your /wp/ directory and write following lines:

```
# ==>Initializaion…
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteBase /

# ==>Set default file
DirectoryIndex index.php

#==> If the requested resource is NOT a file, or the URL contains “/wp/” anywhere in it,
# then serve the default file instead
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /wp/
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

If someone types “/wp/” anywhere in the address bar, they will not see what is in it. Instead, they will see your homepage.

You may have to adjust the code to suite your requirement.